How to read a txt file in pandas where head fields are in lines?
I have a txt file like below, where some data have the ":" as value, and  between each record there is two blank lines
Serial#  : 356899
LDEV : 0
SL : 0
CL : 0
VOL_TYPE : OPEN-V-CVS        
VOL_Capacity(BLK) : 104857600
NUM_PORT : 0
PORTs :
F_POOLID : NONE
VOL_ATTR : CVS : HDP
CMP : -
EXP_SPACE : -
B_POOLID : 1
LDEV_NAMING : 
STS : NML
OPE_TYPE : NONE
OPE_RATE : 100
MP# : 0
ASSIGNED_MP# : 0
SSID : 8000
Used_Block(BLK) : 0
FLA(MB) : Disable
RSV(MB) : 0
CSV_Status : DISABLED
CSV_PROGRESS(%) : -
CSV_Mode : DISABLED
COMPRESSION_ACCELERATION : -
COMPRESSION_ACCELERATION_STATUS : -
CSV_PROCESS_MODE : -
DEDUPLICATION_DATA : DISABLED
ALUA : Disable
RSGID : 0
PWSV_S : -

Serial#  : 356899
LDEV : 5
SL : 0
CL : 0
VOL_TYPE : OPEN-V-CVS        
VOL_Capacity(BLK) : 20971520
NUM_PORT : 2
PORTs : CL1-C-2 1 SH-WINTESTP : CL2-E-1 1 SH-WINTESTP
F_POOLID : NONE
VOL_ATTR : CVS : HORC : HDP
CMP : -
EXP_SPACE : -
B_POOLID : 1
LDEV_NAMING : SH
STS : NML
OPE_TYPE : NONE
OPE_RATE : 100
MP# : 4
ASSIGNED_MP# : 4
SSID : 8000
Used_Block(BLK) : 0
FLA(MB) : Disable
RSV(MB) : 0
CSV_Status : DISABLED
CSV_PROGRESS(%) : -
CSV_Mode : DISABLED
COMPRESSION_ACCELERATION : -
COMPRESSION_ACCELERATION_STATUS : -
CSV_PROCESS_MODE : -
DEDUPLICATION_DATA : DISABLED
ALUA : Disable
RSGID : 0
PWSV_S : -

I tried to read this in pandas but field PORTs and VOL_ATTR is messing the things.
the results should be something like this:
table output example
Serial#     LDEV    SL  CL  VOL_TYPE    VOL_Capacity(BLK)   NUM_PORT    PORTs   F_POOLID    VOL_ATTR    CMP     EXP_SPACE   B_POOLID 
356899  0   0   0    OPEN-V-CVS         104857600   0        NONE    CVS  : HDP  -   -  1
356899  5   0   0    OPEN-V-CVS         20971520    2    CL1-C-2 1 SH-WINTESTP :  CL2-E-1 1 SH-WINTESTP  NONE    CVS :  HORC  : HDP  -   -  1


scanning your post and and some ambiguity, do you mean fields with no value will simply be FIELDNAME : (empty) NEXT_FIELD : (value) NEXT_FIELD :  (value) NEXT_FIELD : (empty) NEXT_FIELD : value ... or something else ?

it is like FILEDNAME : (value) NEXT_FIELD : (value : value) NEXT_FIELD : (value)

Using a regex approach, import re; df = pd.DataFrame([dict(re.findall(r"(.+?)\s*:\s*(.+)", rec)) for rec in re.split(r"\n{2,}", open("file.txt").read())]).
